# why don't List<T>.GetHashCode and ObservableCollection<T>.GetHashCode evaluate their items?

Tags: c#, hashcode

I think it is strange that the GetHashCode function of these collections don't base their hashcode on the items in their lists.

I need this to work in order to provide dirty checking (you have unsaved data).
I've written a wrapping class that overrides the GetHashCode method but I find it weird that this is not the default implementation.

I guess this is a performance optimization?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new ObservableCollection<test>();
        int hash = x.GetHashCode();
        x.Add(new test("name"));
        int hash2 = x.GetHashCode();

        var z = new List<test>();
        int hash3 = z.GetHashCode();
        z.Add(new test("tets"));
        int hash4 = z.GetHashCode();

        var my = new CustomObservableCollection<test>();
        int hash5 = my.GetHashCode();
        var test = new test("name");
        my.Add(test);
        int hash6 = my.GetHashCode();
        test.Name = "name2";
        int hash7 = my.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class test
{
    public test(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is test)
        {
            var o = (test) obj;
            return o.Name == this.Name;
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int collectionHash = base.GetHashCode();

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var itemHash = item.GetHashCode();
            if (int.MaxValue - itemHash > collectionHash)
            {
                collectionHash = collectionHash * -1;
            }
            collectionHash += itemHash;
        }
        return collectionHash;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare collections for equality based on their content, you can use the F# collections, or, better yet, use F#.  The F# collections can define comparison operations based on their contents because they are immutable.  If you do not want to learn F#, you can still use the collections from your C# code by adding a reference to the F# assemblies.  Microsoft has also released a set of immutable collections that are more idiomatic to C#, but they do not seem to have defined comparison operators for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it did, it would break a few of the [guidelines for implementing `GetHashCode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx). Namely:

> the integer returned by GetHashCode should never change

Since the content of a list can change, then so would its hash code.

> the implementation of GetHashCode must be extremely fast

Depending on the size of the list, you could risk slowing down the calculation of its hash code.

Also, I do not believe you should be using an object's hashcode to check if data is dirty. [The probability of collision is higher than you think](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The Equals/GetHashCode of lists checks for reference equality, not content equality. The reason behind this is, that lists are both **mutable** and by reference (not struct) objects. So every time you change the contents, the hash code would change.

The common use case of hash codes are hash tables (for example `Dictionary<K,V>` or HashSet), which sort their items based on hash when the are first inserted into the table. If the hash of an object wich is already in the table changes, it may no longer be found, wich leads to erratic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The key of `GetHashCode` is to reflect the `Equals()` logic, in a light weight way.

And `List<T>.Equals()` inherits `Object.Equals()`, and `Object.Equals()` compares the equality by reference, so that the list do not based on it's items, but the list itself

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have a couple types which behaved like `List<T>` and could generally be used interchangeably with it, but with `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods which would define equivalence either in terms of the sequence of identities, or the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` behaviors of the items encapsulated therein.  Making such methods to behave efficiently, however, would require that the class include code to cache its hash value but invalidate or update the cached hash value whenever the collection was modified (it would not be legitimate to modify a list while it was stored as a dictionary key, but it should be legitimate to remove a list, modify it, and re-add it, and it would be very desirable to avoid having such modification necessitate re-hashing the entire contents of the list).  It was not considered worthwhile to have ordinary lists go through the effort of supporting such behavior at the cost of slowing down operations on lists that never get hashed; nor was it considered worthwhile to define multiple types of list, multiple types of dictionary, etc. based upon the kind of equivalence they should look for in their members or should expose to the outside world.